# Schichttorte; a 20 layer German broiled cake

Tags: baking

I am making the cake named above, which I found on a British baking site. It call s for 5 1/2 oz of reg flour-sifted, and 2 1/4 oz of sifted corn flour. ? Does anyone know if this recipe in this context is calling for actual corn "flour" or is it cornstarch?
  Hope someone has the correct answer for me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: It is the very same thing. There is no difference (except the name)

Comment: Hi Sandy, it is not "in this context", it is standard British terminology.

Comment: @Johannes_B in most places around the world, corn flour and cornstarch are not synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

Actual corn "flour" is not a traditional ingredient in Schichttorte. The common translation of corn flour translates to the German equivalent of "corn starch".

To be sure, you can have a look at different recipes for "Baumkuchen". It's the same batter as for Schichttorte, but baked on a stake instead of a flat surface.

Comment: The OP states that the recipe was from a British source. That means it uses what's known in Britain as corn flour. The same product happens to be called corn starch in other places.